# Converting JSON into Table (PowerQuery)

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

What would be a correct PowerQuery syntax to extract the information from this Web JSON into a table:
I'm not very familiar with PowerQuery, and this is probably the only time I'll need this, so I'd be grateful if someone would help me out without refering me to documentation. Thanks

```
[{"time_entry_group": {"minutes": 301,"time_entries_params": {"locked": "0","from": "2021-02-01","to": "2021-02-28","customer_id": "11223344","project_id": "223388","service_id": "435248"},"revenue": 57691.6666666667,"project_id": 223388,"project_name": "Scrb","service_id": 435248,"service_name": "Meetings","month": "202102"}}
, {"time_entry_group": {"minutes": 1175,"time_entries_params": {"locked": "1","from": "2021-01-01","to": "2021-01-31","customer_id": "11223344","project_id": "223388","service_id": "421393"},"revenue": 225208.333333333,"project_id": 223388,"project_name": "Scrb","service_id": 421393,"service_name": "Design","month": "202101"}}
, {"time_entry_group": {"minutes": 24,"time_entries_params": {"locked": "1","from": "2021-01-01","to": "2021-01-31","customer_id": "11223344","project_id": "3168911","service_id": "95033"},"revenue": 4600.0,"project_id": 3168911,"project_name": "youkn Dev","service_id": 95033,"service_name": "Reviews","month": "202101"}}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, if you have a column that you need to expand, you can instead click this arrow icon to the right of the column name. Clicking it should display a menu that should then allow you to specify which nested columns you want to get expand or get at. To be clear, it will expand that column for *all* rows in that table, not just one.

[image: Expand column icon]

---

The JSON you've included is basically an array of objects, so maybe use:

1. `Json.Document` to parse the JSON, which should give you a list of records
2. `Table.FromRecords` to turn the list of records into a table.
3. `Table.ExpandRecordColumn` to expand a nested record columns.

Example implementation:

```
let
    json = "[{""time_entry_group"":{""minutes"":301,""time_entries_params"":{""locked"":""0"",""from"":""2021-02-01"",""to"":""2021-02-28"",""customer_id"":""11223344"",""project_id"":""223388"",""service_id"":""435248""},""revenue"":57691.6666666667,""project_id"":223388,""project_name"":""Scrb"",""service_id"":435248,""service_name"":""Meetings"",""month"":""202102""}},{""time_entry_group"":{""minutes"":1175,""time_entries_params"":{""locked"":""1"",""from"":""2021-01-01"",""to"":""2021-01-31"",""customer_id"":""11223344"",""project_id"":""223388"",""service_id"":""421393""},""revenue"":225208.333333333,""project_id"":223388,""project_name"":""Scrb"",""service_id"":421393,""service_name"":""Design"",""month"":""202101""}},{""time_entry_group"":{""minutes"":24,""time_entries_params"":{""locked"":""1"",""from"":""2021-01-01"",""to"":""2021-01-31"",""customer_id"":""11223344"",""project_id"":""3168911"",""service_id"":""95033""},""revenue"":4600,""project_id"":3168911,""project_name"":""youkn Dev"",""service_id"":95033,""service_name"":""Reviews"",""month"":""202101""}}]",
    parsed = Json.Document(json),
    initialTable = Table.FromRecords(List.Transform(parsed, each [time_entry_group])),
    expanded = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(initialTable, "time_entries_params", {"locked", "from", "to", "customer_id"})
in
    expanded
```

One thing about the code above is that it doesn't expand nested fields `project_id` and `service_id` (present within `time_entries_params`). This is because these columns already exist in the table (and having duplicate column names would cause an error). I've assumed this isn't a problem, as the nested values aren't different.

Comment: I'm afraid that's the part I'm missing. I have a query producing 3 records, and I can click (drill down) those records, and each time I drill down, I get a new applied step, but for one record only. But how do I get everything (both leveröls) displayed as a 2D Table? I'm totally beginner in this.

Comment: @Mara, have edited my answer to give an example for expanding nested columns.

Comment: perfect, you've saved my day!